# How to change the background color of current line in PhpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

PhpStorm 2021.1. How can I change the background color of current line in editor?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be configured at *Settings/Preferences | Editor | Color Scheme | General | Editor | Caret row*.